# how to retrieve specific chart in power point slide using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a power point slide which has multiple charts (multiple bar and line chart)
i need to update them using apache POI library. so far i used to have one chart per slide  and i used to get the chart using below code to identify and update the values.

```
    XSLFChart chart = null;
    for(POIXMLDocumentPart part : mainSlide.getRelations()){
        if(part instanceof XSLFChart){
            chart = (XSLFChart) part;
            break;
        }
    }
```

not sure how to identify specific chart dont see any method like i could identify like shape

```
    for(XSLFSlide slide:ppt.getSlides()){
        for (XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
            if (shapeName.equals(shape.getShapeName()))
                return slide;
        }

    }
```

i gave name to table,textbox in powerpoint and can retrieve in code using shapename but dont see anything for chart . can any one help me plz?

Answer (score 1):

i figured out a way to identify that with help of office mate.

first give a title to chart in power point open layout> chart title> above chart then give any name . to hide that title keep the font size small and make font color as white .

add code in java as below

```
private XSLFChart getChartObject(XSLFSlide mainSlide,String chartName) throws IOException
{
    XSLFChart chart = null;
    for(POIXMLDocumentPart part : mainSlide.getRelations()){
        if(part instanceof XSLFChart){
            chart = (XSLFChart) part;
            if(chart.getCTChart().getTitle()!=null && chart.getCTChart().getTitle().getTx()!=null){

            if(chart.getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPList().get(0).getRList().get(0).getT().equals(chartName))
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return chart;
}
```